# Reusable Function to Edit CSS

Tags: javascript

I have searched for a solution for this. I am unable to use jQuery and struggle with JavaScript but it must be in JavaScript.

I would like to use a function to edit a child of a div that I click. I would also like to reuse the function on the

Here is the markup:

```js
function expdr() {
 if (this.style.display == "block") {
  this.style.display = "none";
 } else {
  this.style.display = "block";
 }
}
```

```css
.bigMe    {display: block;}
```

```html
<div id="whole">

 <div id="bleb" onclick="expdr()">
   <h2>Headline Here!</h2>
   <p>Paragraph here also. Isn't it a lovely day? Actually I'm asking because I'm stuck in an office.</p>
   <div class="bigMe">
     <p>This is a paragraph in a second comp class</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="bloab" onclick="expdr()">
      <h2>Headline Here!</h2>
   <p>Paragraph here also. Isn't it a lovely day? Actually I'm asking because I'm stuck in an office.</p>
   <div class="bigMe"> <!-- Div ARRAY = 4 -->
     <p>This is a paragraph in a second comp class</p>
   </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Thank you in advance for going easy on me, again, I struggle with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid doing things inline - this can cause issues down the road and can get rather messy. It's better to do it all together.

https://jsfiddle.net/22vjokv2/

Let's walk through this -

First off we are going to remove our inline JS call and add a class to our containers -

```
<div id="whole">
    <div id="bleb" class='article'>
         <h2>Headline Here!</h2>

        <p>Paragraph here also. Isn't it a lovely day? Actually I'm asking because I'm stuck in an office.</p>
        <div class="bigMe" id='bigMe1'>
            <p>This is a paragraph in a second comp class</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bloab" class='article'>
         <h2>Headline Here!</h2>

        <p>Paragraph here also. Isn't it a lovely day? Actually I'm asking because I'm stuck in an office.</p>
        <div class="bigMe" id='bigMe2'>
            <!-- Div ARRAY=4 -->
            <p>This is a paragraph in a second comp class</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice I also gave an `ID` to each `bigMe` just to make things more clear on how this works.

The next thing we need to do is define our elements & attach some listeners, this is essentially what your `onclick` was doing but is doing it the right way in `JS`.

```
var articles = document.getElementsByClassName("article");

for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    articles[i].addEventListener("click", expdr, false);
};
```

Here I am defining `articles` by searching for that class, remember I added the class of `article` to the `bigMe` element?

Then I loop over those elements and assign a listener by index, I say `onclick` fire `expdr` and the `false` is bubbling.

Next lets make stuff happen -

```
function expdr() {
    var bigMe = this.querySelector('.bigMe');
    switch (bigMe.style.display) {
        case "block":
            bigMe.style.display = "none";
            break;
        case "none":
            bigMe.style.display = "block";
            break;
        default:
            bigMe.style.display = "none";
            break;
    }
}
```

So you can keep the function `expdr` but you need to make some changes. The first thing we want to do is get our child element. In this case it's `bigMe` and I use the `querySelector()` to find it. Notice that I am saying `this.querySelector` the reason I can use `this` is because the element calling the method is `articles` so `this == article` that was clicked.

Now that we have the `bigMe` we need to do things with it. A switch statement is going to be more effective here. The reason being is that in JS when you have an IF it will evaluate all the way down. So if you check for `block` and change to `none` then in the next statement you check for `none` it will think the element is set to `none` so set it back to block. Nothing can happen.

A switch statement has breaks. Once a statement has evaluated as `true` then it executes anything in its block and exits. I also added in a `default` statement which is the catch all that will ensure that no matter what SOMETHING will happen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wish I had enough reputation to upvote this. Thank you, thank you, thank you Drew. It worked and now I'm going to study this for hours.

Have a good one!